# commiting only deleted files to subversion

Tags: svn

Say I have a large working directory and I am in the process of cleaning out sections of code that are no longer used.  Part of this process is flat out `svn delete`ing a lot of files.  But what if I want to make sure those files are not being used anywhere anymore... if I do `svn commit` it will commit all of my other code changes which I don't wish to test at the moment, and if I try to `svn commit <deleted file list>` it says those files are not under version control (I already did `svn delete` on them).

How can I commit changes to only `svn delete`d files?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Cannot reproduce.

`svn commit <list of svn delete'd files>` works fine.

You will get `svn: <file> is not under version control` error if you try to commit changes to a file that has already been `svn delete'd` ***and committed***.  Is there an errant file in your list?

Comment: ouch, you are completely correct.  i was listing the files with improper syntax.  i just tested it with a single file and it worked fine.  thanks for the answer, i thought this was totally strange to not work.

Answer (score 12):

You also could use changelists
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.changelists.html

First, delete files:

```
$ svn rm path/to/file1
$ svn rm path/to/file2
```

Then, add this files to changelist:

```
$ svn changelist <listname> path/to/file1 path/to/file2
```

or

```
$ svn changelist <listname> path/to/file1
$ svn changelist <listname> path/to/file2
```

And then you can commit *only changelist*

```
$ svn commit --changelist <listname> -m "Comment goes here"
```

BTW, this way you can commit other files in parts

Answer (score 0):

You can "shelve" your changes in subversion, commit, and then take your changes back off the shelf into your working directory.

See http://markphip.blogspot.com/2007/01/shelves-in-subversion.html for details.

Be sure to read the entire post and understand what's going on (pay special attention to the "better method" section). Shelving isn't a "feature" of Subversion, but it's still possible.